# Django Unittest runs into Error

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-unittest

*Environment:*
Intellij PyCharm, Python Django, Sqlite3

I use a standard Django setup project. 
I try to write some Unittests, but I run into the following error.
After some research, I ended up here.

*DB Config*

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

*Code of tests.py*

```
from django.test import TestCase as djangoTestCase
import os
import unittest

# Create your tests here.
class TestExample(djangoTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        print('setup')
        print(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

    def test_abc(self):
        self.assertEqual(1,1)

    def tearDown(self):
        print('tearDown')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

*This is the output*

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

I tried to find the mistake by reading documentation, but without success.
What could be the problem?

Comment: How are you running the tests? Does `python manage.py test` from the shell work?

Comment: Yes, it works very well. Do you have some experiance with PyCharm?  If I start the test there, I run into the descriped error.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with the PyCharm configuration.

Comment: Ok, but thank you for your hint! :)

Answer (score 1):

With django test you don't need this part:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

you just running tests with `python manage.py test` command.

Comment: ok, thank you. It work by the cmd- command, but not with --> Test at PyCharm

Comment: In Pycharm you need to add Run/Debug cunfiguration. Select as script `manage.py` file. And specify as script paramethers `test`.

Comment: Check this docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem in PyCharm. My DB config is in file `config.settings_dev`. By default, PyCharm is not aware of it.

To solve it,

1. Open PyCharm's Run/Debug Configurations in menu `Run` -> `Edit Configurations`
2. Expand `Templates`, then `Djano tests`.
3. Add environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` with value `config.settings_dev` (replace it with your own settings file)

[image: PyCharm Run Config Templates]

4. Delete any existing configurations under `Django tests`

[image]
 5. Run the tests in PyCharm